# R code block causes LaTeX errors with Knitr

Tags: pdftex, r, knitr

I am using R with knittr and LaTeX. I have isolated some error that has been occuring the following block:

```
<<>>=
opt_vals <- data.frame(opt_length=numeric(2000),
                       opt_eggs=numeric(2000))
for (i in 1:2000){
  sim_fit <- fitted(model2)+rnorm(18, 0, sd(stdres2))
  sim_data <- data.frame(sim_fit, 
                       length=data_set$length, 
                       length2=data_set$length2 )

  model4 <- lm(sim_fit ~ length + length2, data = sim_data)

  #Optimale laengde
  optimal_length <- -coef(model4)[2]/(2*coef(model4)[3])

  opt_vals$opt_length[i] <- optimal_length

  #Maximalt forventede aeg
  max_expected_eggs <- coef(model4)[1]-
    (coef(model4)
[2]^2/(4*coef(model4)[3]))

  opt_vals$opt_eggs[i] <- max_expected_eggs
  }
@
```

Whenever I include this code in my Knittr document, I get errors about a missing (or extra) $ or a forgotten }

Additional info: When I set  <>= the error disappear so I think it's something in the typesetting, but I am not at all sure about how to fix it.

Edit: I am attaching an screenshot of the errors and code region.

[image: Screen shot of errors and code]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Knits without a problem, and compiles without any errors at all.  However the pdf output tells me that 'model2' is missing.  Run on Win10, with updated MikTex 2.9, and  R 3.1.3 installations.

Comment: I think the last part of your comment was lost :)

Comment: @R.Schumacher That is very odd... I have attached an image showing the errors.

Comment: Did you actually run the knitr command in R on the *.Rnw file.

Comment: I run it from R-studio.

Comment: When I run the code block by itself I also get no errors... and I can't find any syntax errors in my document

Comment: You call on model2 in the line sim_fit <- fitted(model2)+rnorm(18, 0, sd(stdres2)) and model2 has not been defined in this R code block.

Answer (score 1):

It seems something in knitr typesetting is incompatible with the mathtime pro 2 fonts, removing that solves the problem.