# Basic R code yields errors of "unclosed $" in knitr

Tags: r, knitr, overleaf

[image]I cannot use R code in Overleaf Knitr, since any basic code which includes $ yields error of unclosed $.

Even the sample file of knitr in Overleaf itself causes LaTeX error: https://www.overleaf.com/project/5d8acab3589db50001979c7d

The only similar question I've found was [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357297/r-code-block-causes-latex-errors-with-knitr), but it does not provide an answer for my own problem.

Is there any package or anything else I can do?

Comment: [Disclamer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.] Do you mean the sample code at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Knitr? The examples work just fine for me on Overleaf. Note that (from that page) "Documents that contain R code must be saved with the extension .Rtex, otherwise the code won't work."

Comment: Thanks. You are correct, the compiling works fine. But the left side shows error. Please see the print above. I haven't changed anything from the original sample, the filename is originally in the .Rtex extension.

Comment: @LianTzeLim Why Overleaf change do not allow the .Rnw extension? It is clear that this  confuse to some users without apparent advantages.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, do anyone have solution for that please ?

Answer (score 3):

The Oveleaf syntax checker should be disabled in the code block indicating the missing dollar sign error as indicated by Overleaf on this page:

[Disabling Code Check for part of a file](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Code_Check#Disabling_Code_Check_for_part_of_a_file)

Comment: Can you try to sum up what to do rather than posting a link to an external source? Keep the reference, but make sure people who find this post can understand what to do without having to jump elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based in arodriguezsv's one and in https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Code_Check.

You can disable the code check of the file with R script by adding

```
%%novalidate
```

in the beginning of the file. You can also disable a chunk of code enclosing it by

```
%%begin novalidate
Rcode (with syntax error)
%%end novalidate
```

So a solution for your problem can be

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}


%%begin novalidate
<<plot1, fig.pos="t", fig.height=4, fig.width=4, fig.cap="First plot">>=

xdata = read.csv(file="data.txt", head=TRUE,sep=" ")

hist(xdata$data, main="Overleaf histogram", xlab="Data")

@
%%end novalidate


The figure \ref{fig:plot1} is simple histogram.

\end{document}
```